# have to make subcollection inside firebase setup

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I want to make one collection starts with
all_delivery > {hash_id} already generate called `this.delivery_client_hashid` > "this_client_delivey" > {random hash unknwon}

```
const get_id2 = firebase.firestore().collection('all_delivery').doc(this.delivery_client_hashid).collection("this_client_delivery").doc();
```

but I get this error:

> FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must
> have an even number of segments, but
> all_delivery/5BcX5Mf6TujUiOSk6eup/this_client_delivery has 3.

The reason I leave doc to be blank becuase I want random hash, what's the reason for the error and how get I get random hash generate after `"this_client_deliver"`

Comment: It sounds like your `this.delivery_client_hashid` doesn't have a value. You'll want to `console.log(this.delivery_client_hashid)` right before the line of code in your question to verify that.

Comment: I belive I have it, otherwise the error won't show `5BcX5Mf6TujUiOSk6eup`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you edit your question to show the code, its output, and the new error (if any)?